Launching multiple instances of tftpd32
I have 9 boards in parallel that fetch a binary file on a TFTP server hosted with tftpd32 to program one of their microcontroller.
Each board is connected to the PC which hosts the TFTP server with a USB-C cable and the communication protocol is Ethernet-over-USB.
Thus, 9 Ethernet adapters are created with 9 different IP addresses and I have to launch one instance of TFTP server per IP address because I think you can only bind one IP address on tftpd32.
Here is a diagram that shows how boards are connected to the PC:

Is it possible to launch 9 instances of tftpd32.exe with a unique IP address binded to each instance?
I'm on Windows 10

One instance is sufficient.
You need to disable the option Bind TFTP to this address to make TFTP32/64 bind to any local address.

In tftp32.ini this looks like
LocalIP=


Alright, and the equivalent of this option in the ini file is leaving the key "LocalIP" blank I guess? Just tried putting an IP then leaving it blank and I see that the "Bind TFTP to this address" is ticked or unticked depending on what I write in the ini file.

Yes, just leave the line blank after the =.
